# indexing and searching of non-text data

Tags: mongodb, search, indexing, lucene

Is there any efficient way to search for non-text data? For example, let say there are millions of documents of this form:

```
{
  data: [ 
    {attr1: 5, attr2: 4},
    {attr1: 3, attr2: 3},
    {attr1: 1, attr2: 2},
    ... // several hundred more things
  ]
}
```

and I want to find all documents with data which has subarray (of variable length, let say 2 to 10), such as

```
[{attr1: 3, attr2: 3}, {attr1: 1, attr2: 2}].
```

where the order is important. Further, if I want other customization, such as if I allow attr2 to not be the exactly equal values, but near the specified values, does that complicate things a whole lot?

Comment: hm, wondering how lucene should help you here. so far it looks like a mongodb question only

Comment: I think this question is too vague to answer well. Of course there are efficient ways to search for non-text data. But to allow us to give good answers, please explain what your data actually looks like, what you are trying to accomplish, and what you have tried that doesn't work. Because of MongoDB's flexible data models, it's not appropriate to answer "can I/how do I do this?" questions without some understanding of the application space.

Comment: @wdberkeley I don't know how to be more precise, but the data is essentially an array of hundreds of objects with 2 numerical attributes, and the user will search by specifying an array (of length 2 to 10) that is supposed to be a subarray of those array in the data.

Comment: @Mysterion I guess I am not sure whether or not other nosql will help, or if I should just turn the data into text and use text search; but I would think that simply indexing data would not help. My thought is to build an index containing all subarrays of length 10; is that possible in mongodb? Is there a way to search for ordered subarray in mongo?

Comment: OK. It sounds like this would not be easy to do using MongoDB as stated. The reason I ask for more information is because this entire way of searching is very peculiar and makes me curious and makes me wonder if there isn't another way to do the same thing based on knowledge in the application space.

Comment: @wdberkeley: There are various examples I have encountered where I am wondering one can search for subpath of a database of paths, such as path of stock price, geographic path, etc. Do you know of any technology I should explore to just get started?